# Vector Subspaces- Counterexample

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

[image]

ive been struggling to come up with a counter-example, ive been treating V as R^3. I would very much appreciate if someone could come up with a counter example and the right equality involving the equations below.

Comment: WhizKid, can you prove that one side is a subset of the other?

Comment: @JonathanY i doubt I could come up with a proof that would convince me as im not so sure of the definition of adding subspaces together , I take this is simply just combining the elements in the set of the subspace.

Comment: Well, addition isn't the same as a union, otherwise both propositions would've been correct. Instead, you look for $\{u+w\mid u\in U,w\in W\}$, which of course contains all $u=u+0$, $w=0+w$, but much more. Therefore showing that both equations fail due to one direction (i.e., the other is correct) will help us know how to try to construct a counter-example.

Comment: @JonathanY. ok i get the whole idea it isnt an union but I can't seem to picture it mentally in R^3 although I can manipulate algebraically if that makes sense. I will also follow your advice to look for an example in R^2, lastly I would like to ask a question if I wanted to make the above equalities true, how would I have to alter them?

Comment: WhizKid it makes *a lot* of sense. These things takes time. I encourage you to try to think of other examples, in other spaces; there are many non-equivalent examples, and 'practice makes perfect' ;)

Comment: To address your last question, note that in (a) we have $\subset$ and in (b) $\supset$ instead of equalities. Beyond that, I'm not sure one could represent (a)'s LHS and (b)'s RHS in a clearer way.

Comment: @JonathanY. yh i realised that, thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your idea of $V=\mathbb{R}^3$:

a) Let $T=\{(t,t,0);t\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $U=\{(x,0,z);x,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $W=\{(0,y,z);y,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$.

$T+(U\cap W)=\{(t,t,z);t,z\in\mathbb{R}\}$

$(T+U)\cap(T+W)=\mathbb{R}^3$

b) Let $T=\{(x,0,0);x\in\mathbb{R}\}$, $U=\{(0,y,0);y\in\mathbb{R}\}$ and $W=\{(t,t,0);t\in\mathbb{R}\}$

$(T+U)\cap W=W$

$(T\cap W)+(U\cap W)=\{0\}$

Comment: Nice. BTW, one could find a single example for both, in $\mathbb{R}^2$. @WhizKid, you might want to look for such an example.

Answer (score 0):

Let T be a line in R3 and let U and W be distinct planes in R3 (where T, U, and W all touch the origin). Assume T does not lie in either U or W.

U intersect W is a line through the origin. So adding T will give a plane touching the origin. (LHS)

On the right side we get R3 intersect R3, or R3. So LHS does not equal RHS.

Modify this argument slightly to prove part (b).